# Assigning 5 static IP addresses to different routers

Tags: networking

I have a Towerstream modem with 5 static IPs, (one network port).
How can I assign different IP addresses to different routers?

Comment: I may not understand your question... If you have 5 different routers and 5 different IP's but only one Ethernet port from your ISP, you would put in a switch between the modem and routers... What else could you do in this situation or do I not understand the question?

Comment: You need better router.  The 8 port Ubiquiti (ubnt.com) perhaps.  Or the 5 port and a managed switch.  With that  type of router you can route all 5 IPs with the single router to a single or many local network ranges or vLans.h

Comment: @acejavelin he needs a different class of router.  Until recently it was pricey.  There are good less expensive options now tho.

Comment: @Tyson You can't really say he "needs a better router" with the information given, he simply asked how to assign different IP's to different routers with one Ethernet port on his modem. If he has a simple switch and 5 different routers, he is set. Without knowing more about how network(s) need to be configured, it is impossible to recommend anything definitively.

Comment: @acejavelin you have a point, with some connection types an unmanaged switch and 5 different routers might work, depends how the IPs are assigned tho.  For one $50 router tho you can bind all 5 static IPs to the same local network and route locally however.  Why would anyone want 5 routers with 5 accompanying local networks?

Comment: @Tyson We see this all the time, especially where smaller, SOHO type companies share an internet connection... They split the cost of having 5 IP's and then put in a switch and each gets their own IP address. Or the company may have it's data router, the VoIP provider has it's own router, the HVAC company has it's own router, the ATM company has it's own router, the entertainment provider has it's own router, etc... There are many applications where this may be necessary, although it isn't necessarily optimal in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

How many ports do your modem have?
If less than five ports, you need a switch to add your ports.
Later, connect your routers to the switch and go to your router’s setting page and set the static IP address for your routers.

Here’s how to do it in five easy steps:
1.Fire up your  router’s Web configuration screen and click on its Setup tab.
2.From there, click on Network Settings on the sidebar.
3.Scroll down to the Add DHCP Reservation section, check the Enable box and add your device’s name.
4.Add your device’s IP Address and MAC Address. The IP Address you choose will need to fall within your router’s DHCP UP Address Range (see the DHCP Server Settings section directly above). You should be able to locate your devices MAC Address on the bottom of the device itself.
5.Click Save

An example: 
[image]